# How do I pass a value into nodeJS from another client-side javascript document?

Tags: node.js, json, nlp, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I'm currently new to node.js, and I am making a chat-bot based application. However, the IBM Natural Language Understanding API does not have documentation for regular javascript code, and instead requires the utilization of the nodeJS server. I had no knowledge of nodeJS beforehand.

The application is intended to work as follows: A user types in a large corpus of text, then the "chatbot" sends the text to FireBase and to a nodeJS module to have main keywords extracted by the IBM API. These main keywords are then stored into Firebase and then extracted from firebase by the web application to display the keyword text. I tried to run node.js, but I cannot seem to pass the variable from the chatBox into nodeJS. I am also using localhost:5000  as a port for my website. Where is my logic flawed, and what is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide some snippets of your code and explicit examples of what you want to do, and what interfaces you have available.

Comment: How do you "pass the variable"?  From the high level description you've provided it seems that you need to make and XHR call from your client side javascript to the node.js server hosted on localhost:5000. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you using a web-framework like express with your node.js app. If not then you should take a node.js / express tutorial, which will show you how to create HTTP POST routes, which you can invoke from browser side HTML / Javascript.